# data that non changing frequently in drupal - how to do it right?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, query-optimization, cache-control

i got a form (using form api and drupal_Get form ) and i got a form with 50 fields and some of them are non frequently chaning data like hobbies, year of birth , city/country etc...
i currently do just them in array in file and put them in #options=>$array ... is that the fastest way to save resources? or should i use taxonomy/variable_set/database query/block/node or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `variable_get/variable_Set` : Is generally used to store **admin preferences** for the **site**. If these are user specific I don't think it's a good idea to save them using variable_set
- `taxonomy` : Can also be used for populating the values of
  **drop-downs**, that is for options in the listing. In your case create a vocabulary
  called **hobbies** and add
  *swimming,reading,drupaling* as terms.
  Then use the [content-taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) 
  to use taxonomy terms as drop downs using CCK moudule.
- `nodes` : Anything that is **user
  specific** should go in as nodes. And
  any **content** that can be **created by
  the users** should also go in as nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For administering forms you can use [variable_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/6)/[variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6).

But for your task it seems like that users enter their bio, so in this case you should store each form submission to new "row", as you do now for file (wonder why you don't use DB storing).